# Samsung 830 256GB SSD dying?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, performance

I have a decent fast Computer (i7, 32 GB RAM, SSD, ...), which worked flawlessly for a year now, but about over a week ago the access rates just went bananas (well, very slow like on HDDs).

Just some examples:

Adobe products just load as slow as they did on earlier on HDDs. Usually, I clicked the icon and Photoshop was fully loaded in about 5 seconds. Now it tends to be 10 to 20.

When loading a map in an online game like CSGO, I usually have been the first on the server. Now, it really takes so much more time.

The boot-up procedure also takes more time.

Even smaller programmes like IE, Firefox, Opera are just double the times slower in loading.

I checked back on that week, but I have not installed or changed anything within the last two months.

As usually with SSDs, Prefetch, Superfetch, Indexing, ... etc. are turned off.

I have a very fair feeling, my SSD is dying, but how can I be for sure now or what is to do now in general? Thank you in advance, mates.

Comment: The device itself should report its health.  Samsung should have a tool that reports the health of their devices.

Comment: Its called magician. Its pretty handy

Comment: From the massive amount of research I did before buying an ssd for my mac, that sounds like a TRIM issue.  Specifically, since it's detecting AHCI is not enabled (whether or not it is enabled is entirely irrelevant, the software needs to think it is), TRIM isn't enabled, and so your drive performance is suffering.

Comment: Unfortunately, TRIM is not the problem. I checked it with "fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify", which gave me an output of "0". That means, TRIM is activated.

Comment: Symptom of older Samsung drivers… Are drivers up to date? Did you run the Restoration function from Magician?

Comment: post a picture of this tool: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html

Comment: There is no "restoration function" in Samsung Magician. Here is the screenshot of the tool: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3970/xooxtchu_jpg

Comment: I also updated the Mainboard BIOS to its newest (Gigabyte Z77X-UH3D) and those Intel INF drivers, too. Still showing no AHCI mode and still slow loading behaviour.

Comment: the SSD is fine. If you are on IDE mode, do this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/922976 and go into BIOS/UEFI and change to AHCI

Comment: I know this is an older question, but it does not seem to be solved yet and one thing is not yet mentioning: cooling. Slow downs over time are also common when the CPU cooler is clogged and thermal protection kicks the CPU to lower speeds.